# C# - Having a List<someInterface> and want to retrieve the different objects that use that interface not using foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have two classes:

```
public class Article : IPosition    
public class AssemblyGroup : IPosition
```

I have a `List<IPosition> positions` where I have items from both classes as ItemsSource for my view.
Now I want to retreive the different objects like

```
var articlePositions = positions.Where(all Article objects)
var assemblyGroupPositions = positions.Where(all AssemblyGroup objects)
```

Is there any other way other than a foreach loop and adding every item of the list to another list?

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah you should be using OfType<>

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159906 . Your question sounds a bit like it's defeating the purpose of using an `interface`.

Comment: why do you keep them in a single collection in the first place?

Comment: @NateW I need those two when I want to save some changes. As my database needs the specific class type I need to split my interface. Everything else works with the interface. Thank you for the link and the additional info.

Comment: Consider adding a method to your interface `Save()`. Then, each individual implementation of the interface or object repository can handle saving it, rather than the class that's calling the interface.

Comment: @NateW Thank you, I will try it with a save method in my interface.

Comment: @MongZhu I have two different types that can be a position. As the two types are saved in two different tables in my database, I had to implement the interface to show both in one list for my position view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you should be using `OfType<>` which will grab only the things of that type.

```
positions.OfType<Article>()
positions.OfType<AssemblyGroup>()
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed (haven't found that one with Google)

Comment: I'm here to help :).