# Dotnet Core Dependency injection, How to Register multiple instances of same class

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection

I want to know if it is possible using build in dotnet core DI framework to register multiple instances of the same class

For example I have a class `ToDo` that sends off messages to clients. I want 2 instances of the same `ToDo` object with different injected configuration objects. So at the end I will have 2 separate instances of `ToDo` object.

Is this possible?

---

**Edit:**

Suppose I have a pattern `pub/sub`

I have a generic class called `MessageSubService.cs` and the implementation looks something like this

```
public class ASBMessageSubService : ASBSubService, IASBSubService
{
       public ASBMessageSubService(..., IOptions<ASBSubOptions> options): base(options)
}
```

So based on this I have multiple ASBMessageSubService that I will need to create. The only thing will differ is the `IOptions` that passed in. `IOptions` is internal access. I can not access that property if I use `provider.GetRequireServices<T>`.

I do understand I can do this

```
service.AddSingleton<ASBMessageSubService, IASBSubService>
service.AddSingleton<ASBMessageSubService, IASBSubService>
service.AddSingleton<ASBMessageSubService, IASBSubService>
```

This will register me 3 different instances. The issue is The implementation is that same and I will not be able to resolve it by the type where `nameof(ASBMessageSubService);

I can also register a `deligate` where I can resolve it based on name or type but this runs into same issue I described above, the type of implementation will be the same.

(I am aware that I can use libraries like `structuremap` or `autofac` to get this done with registering them as named instance. However I would like to avoid 3rd party tools like this in this project. )

Any suggestions on this?

Thank you!

Comment: You call `services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(...)` multiple times and your consumer classes can take an `IEnumerable<IMyService>` for example.

Comment: @DavidG Thank you. I am aware of this approach. However, My services are singletons and what I am confused from this example is that once I inject `IEnumnerable<>` How will I know what instance to get, since the underneath implementations is that same?  For example I will register same `ToDoService` multiple times per `IToDo` interface. ?

Answer (score 2):

David G answered it. I'll expand it slightly to help you and others.

You can register multiple classes, either as themselves, or as an interface:

e.g.

```
services.AddTransient<Todo>(provider => new Todo(configuration1));
services.AddTransient<Todo>(provider => new Todo(configuration2));
services.AddTransient<Todo>(provider => new Todo(configuration3));
...
services.AddTransient<ITodoWorker, NeedTodos>();
```

And then for dependency injection take a dependency on `IEnumerable<Todo>`:

```
public class NeedTodos : ITodoWorker
{
    public NeedTodos(IEnumerable<Todo> todos)
    {
        foreach (var todo in todos)
        {
            if (todo.Id == "configuration1")
            {
                // an idea if you need to find a specific Todo instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need more elaborate DI, definitely check out Scrutor (https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor)

Comment: Thank you, the issue with this solution is that `todo.Id` will not be accessible since it will be provided by DI as well and will be `private readonly`  at each implementation. I think what I will need is a `NamedInstance` to be able to resolve services by name

Comment: OK. You would have to provide a real example then if you want further help. I've only ever needed to use the `Id` like approach above, or I've only needed to just process every `Todo` (i.e. not single out an instance)

Comment: Update the question.

Answer (score 0):

This declaration is probably around the wrong way, if that's not just an editing mistake:

```
service.AddSingleton<ASBMessageSubService, IASBSubService>
```

should most likely be:

```
service.AddSingleton<IASBSubService, ASBMessageSubService>
```

Then your class take those as multiple dependences, like this:

```
public class Subscribers
{
    public Subscribers(IEnumerable<IASBSubService> subs)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

As for finding a specific instance, what is in `ASBSubOptions` that will differentiate an `IASBSubService`?

Let me guess and say it's a property `Name`. A subscriber might have a name. In that case:

```
public interface IASBSubService
{
    string Name { get; }
    ...
}
```

then:

```
public class ASBMessageSubService : IASBSubService, ...
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public ASBMessageSubService(..., IOptions<ASBSubOptions> options)
    {
        Name = options.Value.SubscriberName;
        ...
    }
}
```

Now if we go back to the `Subscribers` class I invented, assuming you have something like this, then you can find an instance by `Name`:

```
public class Subscribers
{
    public Subscribers(IEnumerable<IASBSubService> subs)
    {
        var sub = subs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Service1");
    }
}
```

If it's the concrete type you are after, whether it's an `ASBSubService` or `ASBMessageSubService`, you can get the concrete type using:

```
var sub = subs.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name.GetType() == typeof(ASBSubService));

// GetType() never returns the interface type (I think) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159906/finding-the-concrete-type-behind-an-interface-instance/1159940
```

Exposing *something* in the interface to help you choose the type of instance is probably what you are looking for. That's a very common approach to this type of problem.

Comment: If not, find me on Discord.

Comment: Of course the interface doesn't have to be `Name`. It can be any kind of discriminator you choose. You could return `Type` and expose the underlying type that way. Exposing something in the interface to help you choose the type of instance your after might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Again this will have me expose unwanted properties just to resolve dependencies. If Other member of the team will be consuming this API, I do not think this will scale well, since they would have to provide name  for each implementation. Thank you for the solution and the idea though..

Comment: You need a discriminator. What will your discriminator be? Will it be the type of the implementing class?

Comment: I was looking for something among these lines: https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html this allows you to register you a named instance and be able to resolve it by name at resolution time. I am not sure if there is something like this I can do in dotnet DI framework out of the box.

Comment: I posted a new answer.

Comment: Ah. I understand you better. I'll need to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

This has stretched me a little. I've had to pop the hood on the DI mechanics:

First, the interfaces and classes:

```
public interface ISubService {} // just a second interface I made up

public interface IASBSubService {}

public class ASBMessageSubService : IASBSubService, ISubService
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public ASBMessageSubService(string name)
   {
       Name = name;
   }
}
```

Now, I found a way to re-register existing registered instances as a different interface:

```
services.AddSingleton<ASBMessageSubService>(provider => new SubServiceSubscriber("sub1"));
services.AddSingleton<ASBMessageSubService>(provider => new SubServiceSubscriber("sub2"));
services.AddSingleton<ASBMessageSubService>(provider => new SubServiceSubscriber("sub3"));

// re-register as IASBSubService
foreach (var service in services.Where(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(ASBMessageSubService)).ToList())
{
    services.AddSingleton<IASBSubService >(provider => service.ImplementationFactory(provider) as IASBSubService );
}

// re-register as ISubService
foreach (var service in services.Where(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(ASBMessageSubService)).ToList())
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISubService>(provider => service.ImplementationFactory(provider) as ISubService);
}
```

And then take a dependency on the interface you need:

```
public class Subscriptions
{
    public Subscriptions(IEnumerable<IASBSubService> subs)
    { ... }
}
```

or

```
public class ServiceManager
{
    public ServiceManager(IEnumerable<ISubService> subs)
    { ... }
}
```

If there's a cleaner way, someone else will need to show me.