# Determine class under interface automatically

Tags: c#

`destroyComponentPacket.Component` is an `IComponent` (an interface). I want to determine the specific class under it automatically, without having to do it manually using `switch()`. What are the options for doing so?

```
switch (destroyComponentPacket.Component)
                        {
                            case Tile t:
                                destroyComponentEntity.Detach<Tile>();
                                break;
                            case CollisionActor ca:
                                destroyComponentEntity.Detach<CollisionActor >();
                                break;
                            case Grass g:
                                destroyComponentEntity.Detach<Grass>();
                                break;
                            case Tree t:
                                destroyComponentEntity.Detach<Tree>();
                                break;
                            case Wall w:
                                destroyComponentEntity.Detach<Wall>();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the Concrete Type behind an Interface instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159906/finding-the-concrete-type-behind-an-interface-instance)

Comment: Why you can not call `destroyComponentEntity.Detach<IComponent>()`

Comment: @Chetan it's because the detach method accepts only exact, specific classes as opposed to interfaces.

Comment: @gunr2171, the Detach method accepts classes only `public void Detach<T>()
            where T : class
        {
            var mapper = _componentManager.GetMapper<T>();
            mapper.Delete(Id);
        }` is it possible to the type to a class?

Comment: Even if a full [mcve] isn't possible, can you give more details about your classes?  What is `destroyComponentPacket`?  Is there a non-generic method `Detach(Type type)` as well as the generic `Detach<T>()`?  Or a `Detach(IComponent component)` method that takes an `IComponent` directly?

Comment: IF there is no `Detach(Type)` method, you can use `MakeGenericMethod()` to call `Detach<T>()` via reflection, using `destroyComponentPacket.Component.GetType()` as the generic type.  See [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/232535/3744182), which may be a duplicate.

Comment: Trying to make a Detach method that accepts type.